# Iterating over jQuery DOM elements in coffeescript: $(@). shortcut

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, shortcut

I have a great many loops in my coffeescript that iterate over a collection of DOM elements, and execute more jQuery. These functions tend to look like this:

```
$('.iterable.object').each ->
    $(@).doThis
    $(@).doThat

    ## More complicated usage
    $(@).jqueryPluginCall
        x: $(@).data('attr1')
        x: $(@).data('attr2')

    ## More complicated usage
    $(@).children('ul.animateable').each ->
        if $(@).data('animation') is "fancy"
            $(@).animate fancy: animation
        else
            $(@).animate simple: animation
        $(@).focus(
            ->
                $(@).animate some: more
            , ->
                $(@).animate even: more
        ) ## Or however you do double callbacks
```

I made about 3 typos entering the `$(@).`'s again and again, and it's becoming a pain.

There isn't a shortcut syntax for `$(@)`? It's kind of a pain to type and seems like a pretty common syntax. It'd be cool if it operated similarly to `@` as an automated function caller, like `&doThis` instead of `&.doThis`.

EDIT:
I'd like to be able to define an alias right in javascript after jQuery loads that responds with the DOM element when called `&` and chains to methods `&doThis`, rather than at the top of each loop the way @bennedich suggests below.

Comment: Maybe I'm just getting old, but `$(@)` is already pretty terse....

Comment: I'm kind of fussy. And I have a lot of these guys. (500+)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('.iterable.object').each -> ...` ?

Comment: People tend to forget that often `$("foo").each(function() { $(this).bar(); });` is the same as just `$("foo").bar()`. Isn't it your case?

Comment: I'm actually executing more complicated CS within that loop. This was an example, but I'll update to demonstrate a layer of complexity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about function chaining:

```
$('.iterable.object').each ->
  $(@)
    .doThis()
    .doThat()
```

Or storing `$(@)` to a variable:

```
$('.iterable.object').each ->
  t = $(@)
  t.doThis()
  t.doThat()
```

Or a combination of the two. Last thing I can think of is IDE snippets, e.g. textmate will let you configure letter+TAB be replaced by `$(@)`.

Comment: Personally, if I am going to use a jquery object more than once, I always cache it by placing it in a variable. Improves performance and readability. +1

Comment: I guess the `@`(`this`) is cached already as a variable in the loop's scope, but repeatedly processing it into a jQuery DOM element (`$(@)`) isn't?

Comment: you can do `$('.iterable.object') -> t = $(@).doThis().doThat()` as well all on one line, assuming the methods return the jQuery element